# Doesn't output text from function to console?

Tags: c++

Why doesn't my `GetMeshLocation()` function output a nested function to it `Print()` with the text **Object location is (23x, 61y, 80z)**?
The compiler passes successfully.

```
#include <iostream>

class Mesh
{
public:
    void GetMeshLocation()
    {
        Print("Object location is (23x, 61y, 80z).");
        return;
    }
    const void Print(const std::string print)
    {
        std::cout << _print << std::endl;
        _print = print;
        return;
    }
private:
    std::string _print;
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    Mesh myMesh;
    myMesh.GetMeshLocation();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

*The code is written for practice purposes and is not of any useful nature :)*

Comment: `_print = print;` That comes *after* `_print` was printed already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a variable that is initialized after its usage, till that it's empty. Thus, you need to put this syntax:

```
_print = print;
```

Before using the `cout` statement in the method The method should look like this:

```
const void Print(const std::string print)
{
    _print = print;
    std::cout << _print << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! Such a shameful mistake only I could make :)

Comment: You're not alone in making mistakes, @Quuely — we've all done things like that on occasion.